# Why passing primitive type is not giving me error?

Tags: java, generics

I was reading java documentation from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/ when i came across this paragraph:-

A Simple Box Class
Begin by examining a non-generic Box class that operates on objects of any type. It needs only to provide two methods: set, which adds an object to the box, and get, which retrieves it:

```
public class Box {
    private Object object;

    public void set(Object object) { this.object = object; }
    public Object get() { return object; }
}
```

Since its methods accept or return an Object, you are free to pass in whatever you want, provided that it is not one of the primitive types. There is no way to verify, at compile time, how the class is used. One part of the code may place an Integer in the box and expect to get Integers out of it, while another part of the code may mistakenly pass in a String, resulting in a runtime error.

I ran the following code

```
public class Box {
private Object object;

public void set(Object object) { this.object = object; }
public Object get() { return object; }
}
```

..

```
public class test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Box box = new Box();
    String s = "hello";
    box.set(s);
    System.out.print(box.get());
    Box box2 = new Box();
    int i = 5;
    box2.set(i);
    System.out.print(box2.get());
    }
}
```

But it is not giving any Runtime Error.

Is this due to autoboxing? And if it is so then is there less importance of using generics??

Thank you

Comment: You're never passing any primitive type to box so there is no autoboxing.

Comment: You are not passing a primitive type to your `Box box2`, because you are manually boxing it before by creating an instance of `Integer` and passing the primitive value to it. Try it with `int i = 5;` and then `box2.set(i);`. Do you get an error?

Comment: Also, if you were to pass the primitive directly, yes, there would be autoboxing.

Comment: Sorry i have corrected my code but still i am not getting any error..

Comment: "I have corrected my code but still I am not getting any error". It would seem a terrible correction of code if it all of the sudden would start giving errors.

Comment: @OhleC so why it is written in java documentation by oracle, that it would give an error. Please, could you explain. Sorry for my little knowledge.

Comment: This has nothing to do with generics; you are not using generics anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is indeed auto boxing here:

```
int i = 5;
box2.set(i);
```

`set` expects an `Object` and you are giving it an `int`, so it gets boxed to an `Integer`.

**But that is not the reason why you are not getting an error.**

The paragraph you quoted says that

> One part of the code may place an Integer in the box and expect to get Integers out of it, while another part of the code may mistakenly pass in a String, resulting in a runtime error.

That paragraph is talking about the *same* box! You have created 2 different boxes and put an `Integer` in one and a `String` in the other.

To recreate what that paragraph is saying, you can do something like this:

```
// there is only one box
Box box = new Box();

// one part of your code
box.set(10);

// another part of your code (Imagine box is passed to some other class and you forgot that it actually has an Integer)
String myString = (String)box.get(); // error!
```